# i want to optimize mysql query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Please guys help me to optimize the below query

```
SELECT
        `dti`.`CompanyId`, 
        `dti`.`Samiti`, 
        `dti`.`toll_date`, 
        `dti`.`MajorFee`, 
        `dti`.`MinorFee`, 
        `dti`.`SawalFee`, 
        SUM(dti.Tmwt) as Tmwt, 
        SUM(dti.Localminor) as Localminor, 
        SUM(dti.Swt) as Swt, 
        SUM(dti.Twt) as Twt, 
        SUM(((dti.Tmwt * dti.MajorFee) + (dti.Localminor * dti.MinorFee) + (dti.Swt * dti.SawalFee))) as total_wages, 
        SUM((dti.Twt * dti.govt_charges)) as govt_deduction, 
        SUM((((dti.Tmwt * dti.MajorFee) + (dti.Localminor * dti.MinorFee) + (dti.Swt * dti.SawalFee)) - (dti.Twt * dti.govt_charges))) as net_amount, 

        (SELECT (SUM(ld.amount) + SUM(ld.advance_deduction)) 
          FROM psac_liability_deduction ld 
          WHERE ld.status = "Active" AND 
                ld.from_date >="2017-08-24" AND 
                ld.to_date <="2017-08-31" AND 
                ld.deducted_for = dti.CompanyId
        ) as group_liability_deduction, 

        (SELECT CONCAT(SUM(wi.GroupLiabilityDeduction), "|", SUM(wi.AdvanceWagesDeduction)) 
            FROM psac_wagesitem wi 
            WHERE   wi.status="Active" AND 
                    wi.from_date >= "2017-08-24" AND 
                    wi.to_date <= "2017-08-31" AND 
                    wi.MainGroup=dti.Samiti AND 
                    wi.FishermanId=dti.CompanyId
        ) as wages_deduction, 

        (SELECT CONCAT(SUM(cdp.product_liability), "|", SUM(cdp.wages_liability)) 
            FROM psac_cash_deposited_payment cdp 
            WHERE   cdp.status="Active" AND 
                    cdp.deposit_date >= "2017-08-24" AND 
                    cdp.deposit_date <= "2017-08-31" AND 
                    cdp.maingroup_id=dti.Samiti AND 
                    cdp.fisherman_id=dti.CompanyId
        ) as cash_deposited, 
        `fm`.`Name` as `fishername`, 
        `fm`.`Code` as `fishername_code`, 
        `fm`.`Bank`, 
        `fm`.`IfscCode`, 
        `fm`.`AccountNo`

    FROM `psac_dailytollinfo` `dti`
    LEFT JOIN `psac_fisherman` `fm` ON `fm`.`ID`=`dti`.`CompanyId`
    WHERE 
    `dti`.`status` = 'Active' AND
    `dti`.`toll_date` >= '2017-08-24' AND
    `dti`.`toll_date` <= '2017-08-31'
    GROUP BY `dti`.`toll_date`, `dti`.`CompanyId`
    ORDER BY `dti`.`toll_date` ASC
```

please help me to optimize this query. If i remove sub queries it will works perfect but with subqueries it takes too much time.
below are table structures

**psac_dailytollinfo table**

```
   CREATE TABLE `psac_dailytollinfo` (
      `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `toll_date` date NOT NULL,
      `Point` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `group_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `Samiti` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `DailytollId` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `CompanyId` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `Name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
      `govt_charges` float(15,2) NOT NULL,
      `MajorFee` float(15,2) NOT NULL,
      `MinorFee` float(15,2) NOT NULL,
      `SawalFee` float(15,2) NOT NULL,
      `Cqty` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
      `Cwt` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
      `Rqty` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
      `Rwt` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
      `Mqty` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
      `Mwt` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
      `Kqty` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
      `Kwt` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
      `Aqty` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
      `Awt` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
      `Sqty` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
      `Swt` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
      `Lqty` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
      `Lwt` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
      `Localminor` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
      `Tmqty` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
      `Tmwt` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
      `Tqty` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
      `Twt` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
      `added_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `updated_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `added_date` datetime NOT NULL,
      `updated_date` datetime NOT NULL,
      `action_microtime` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `status` enum('Active','Inactive','Deleted') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Active'
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**psac_liability_deduction table**

```
CREATE TABLE `psac_liability_deduction` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `wages_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `wages_item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `amount` float(15,2) NOT NULL,
  `advance_deduction` float(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `group_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `maingroup_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `deducted_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `deducted_for` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `from_date` date NOT NULL,
  `to_date` date NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('Active','Inactive','Deleted') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Active',
  `added_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `added_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `action_microtime` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**psac_wagesitem table**

```
 CREATE TABLE `psac_wagesitem` (
      `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `wages_for` enum('Fisherman','Group') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Fisherman',
      `wages_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `from_date` date NOT NULL,
      `to_date` date NOT NULL,
      `group_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `MainGroup` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `FishermanId` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `MajorFee` float(15,2) NOT NULL,
      `MinorFee` float(15,2) NOT NULL,
      `SawalFee` float(15,2) NOT NULL,
      `major_wt` float(15,2) NOT NULL,
      `minor_wt` float(15,2) NOT NULL,
      `sawal_wt` float(15,2) NOT NULL,
      `major_wage` float(15,2) NOT NULL,
      `minor_wage` float(15,2) NOT NULL,
      `sawal_wage` float(15,2) NOT NULL,
      `TotalWage` float(15,2) NOT NULL,
      `group_liability` float(15,2) NOT NULL,
      `advance_wages` float(15,2) NOT NULL,
      `GovDeduction` float(15,2) NOT NULL,
      `GroupLiabilityDeduction` float(15,2) NOT NULL,
      `AdvanceWagesDeduction` float(15,2) NOT NULL,
      `final_wages` float(15,2) NOT NULL,
      `added_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `updated_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `added_date` datetime NOT NULL,
      `updated_date` datetime NOT NULL,
      `action_microtime` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `status` enum('Active','Inactive','Deleted') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Active',
      `editable` enum('Lock','Unlock') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Unlock'
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**psac_cash_deposited_payment table**

```
CREATE TABLE `psac_cash_deposited_payment` (
  `deposit_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `deposited_by` enum('Fisherman','Group') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Fisherman',
  `deposit_date` date NOT NULL,
  `group_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `maingroup_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fisherman_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_liability` float(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `wages_liability` float(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `receipt_number` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `remark` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('Active','Inactive','Deleted') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Active',
  `editable` enum('Lock','Unlock') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Unlock',
  `added_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `added_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `action_microtime` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Good luck with that.

Comment: what datasize you are dealing here? how long took it to exectue the above query and what about Indexes, are you using any?

Comment: @ChristianFelix it took 2.5min to execute query, all columns used in where clause are indexed. datasize is 150,000 rows

Comment: then, some optimising work is required...first, resolve each of the subquery by passing it to your main query,  for example the first one:                                      LEFT JOIN psac_liability_deduction ld ON ld.deducted_for = dti.CompanyId AND ld.status = "active " ..........(SUM(ld.amount) + SUM(ld.advance_deduction) shold be accessible in the main query right now

Comment: @ChristianFelix yes it worked . i also use LEFT JOIN in other subqueries too. thanks

Comment: glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

- You understand that you are looking at a full 8 days?  If you only wanted one week, change `<=` to `<`.
- Switch all tables to InnoDB.
- Have a `PRIMARY KEY` for every table -- either a 'natural' PK (composed of one or more columns that, together, uniquely define each row), or an `AUTO_INCREMENT`.
- `dti` needs `INDEX(status, toll_date)`
- Don't use `(m,n)` on `FLOAT`, it leads to an extra roundoff.
- Don't use `FLOAT` for money, it leads to a roundoff.
- `FLOAT` (with or without `(m,n)`) contains no more than 7 significant digits.
- Consider `DECIMAL(11,2)` instead of `float(11,2)`.
- Be cautious about using `latin1` in one table and `utf8` in another -- if you need to `JOIN` on a `VARCHAR`; it must have the same charset and collation in order to use an index.
- Where practical, make the `ORDER BY` identical to the `GROUP BY`.

These *composite* indexes that are likely to help performance:

```
dti:  INDEX(status, toll_date)
ld:   INDEX(status, deducted_for, from_date)
ld:   INDEX(status, deducted_for, to_date)
wi:   INDEX(status, MainGroup, FishermanId, from_date)
wi:   INDEX(status, MainGroup, FishermanId, to_date)
cdp:  INDEX(status, maingroup_id, fisherman_id, deposit_date)
```

(The date must be last; the other column(s) can be in any order.)

If you still have performance problems with the subqueries after you have added those indexes, let's see `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` so we can look again.

Don't splay an array across columns:

```
  `Cqty` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `Cwt` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  etc
```

Consider having `qty` and `wt` as two columns in another table.

Could there be two different values for `MajorFee` in a single day for a single company?  That, and other things say that the `GROUP BY` is improperly formed.